# Timezone and datetime php

Tags: php, datetime

I don't really understand how the datetime works.

for example if I create a dateTime

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->('H');
```

Did the hour will be generated in function to the server time or the user time ?
If this is the server timezone, is there a way to convert it to the user timezone

Thanks for your help

Comment: $date->('H') is not valid code. It lacks a method name.

Answer (score 0):

knowing the current server date such

```
$current = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:m:s")) //return timestamp
```

can add or subtract hours to result your time to set the current date variable at the user level:

```
$new_time = date($current, strtotime('+5 hours')
```

Comment: Thanks but can you do this with datetime ?

Comment: if you can convert to datetime

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side. The hour is generated is server time.

If you want client's(user) time you must use JavaScript.

You maybe want to use JavaScript.

example

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "localtime = new Date();";
echo "alert(localtime.getHours());";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks but I have dates to load from the database, and I prefere using datetime